# Spring Data JDBC support of QueryDSL version 4.x

Tags: spring-data, querydsl

I'm trying to use Spring Data JDBC extension with QueryDSL 4.x version, but the latest Spring Data snapshot still references QueryDSL 3.x as a dependency, which is a problem because QueryDSL changed the package (removing mysema) from 3.x to 4.x.

Is there any way to make this spring data extension work with QueryDSL 4.x, without causing a potential conflict between the two querydsl versions by adding the needed dependencies for 3.x?

My spring data jdbc ext dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-oracle</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you cannot do that. The framework creates an SqlQuery object for you, therefore you will receive an object with a type in version 3.x while your program expects the type defined in version 4.x.

I see two options:

- to download a source code and basing on that, create your own implementation, it is only 7 classes. But you have to remember that it may give you an additional overhead when a spring or querydsl version is uplifted
- to ask the developer to add a support for querydsl 4.x :) https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc-ext/issues

Answer (score 0):

[Infobip Spring Data Querydsl JDBC module](https://github.com/infobip/infobip-spring-data-querydsl#JDBC) provides the QuerydslPredicateExecutor support for the Spring Data JDBC module repositories.
It also adds [QuerydslJdbcFragment](https://github.com/infobip/infobip-spring-data-querydsl/blob/master/infobip-spring-data-jdbc-querydsl/src/main/java/com/infobip/spring/data/jdbc/QuerydslJdbcFragment.java) which exposes `SQLQuery`, `SQLUpdateClause` and delete with `Predicate` functionality.